# Find last cell in a column that matches the value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA script that searches and finds the value of a cell in a column and then offsets 3 columns to the right and places a timestamp. However, I ran into the problem that it does it for the first match it finds in the column but I want it to do it for the last match instead.

```
Private Sub ExitButton_Click()

Dim cell As Range
    Set cell = Range("D1", Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp)).Find(What:=Me.UsId.Value, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If cell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "User ID '" & Me.UsId.Value & "' not found! Please enter the ID used while signing in.", vbExclamation
    Else
        cell.Offset(0, 3) = Format(Now(), "hh:mm AMPM")
    End If

    Me.UsId.Value = ""
    Me.UsId.SetFocus

End Sub
```

I am VERY new to VBA scripting so I am unsure if this is even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to start at the top and add SearchDirection:=xlPrevious and After:=*[the first cell]*. This used to be called tin can looping. Since there is nothing previous to the first cell, it starts at the bottom and looks up.

If you want to look in column D only,

```
with columns("D")
    Set cell = .cells.Find(What:=Me.UsId.Value, After:=.cells(1), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                           LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
end with

If cell Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "User ID '" & Me.UsId.Value & "' not found! Please enter the ID used while signing in.", vbExclamation
Else
    cell.Offset(0, 3) = Now
    cell.Offset(0, 3).numberformat = "hh:mm AM/PM"
End If
```

Comment: I do want it to only look in Column D.Its with a form so I need the IF command in case the value isn't found.`Private Sub ExitButton_Click()

Dim cell As Range
    Set cell = Range("D1", Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp)).Find(What:=Me.UsId.Value, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If cell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "User ID '" & Me.UsId.Value & "' not found! Please enter the ID used while signing in.", vbExclamation
    Else
        cell.Offset(0, 3) = Format(Now(), "hh:mm AMPM")
    End If

End Sub`

Comment: Doesn't `cell = Range("D1"` set it to just look in D?

Comment: The trick is the After:=... parameter coupled with SearchDirection. With your version it would be something like `set cell = Range("D:D").Find(..., ..., After:Range("D1"), ...`

Comment: My mistake,  when the page originally loaded it only showed me the `With` to `End With` section and therefore, it did not make any sense. 

You are correct. On my version I added your `SearchDirection:=xlPrevious` and it works as well. 

Thank you very much. :)

Comment: But I like your code version better so I will use that one instead :P